# Is using text-fill-color for clipping text in css actually necessary?

Tags: html, css

In CSS3, it is possible to "clip" text so that it appears cut out, such that you can see the background behind it, by using

```
-webkit-background-clip: text;
```

in combination with

```
-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
```

We use prefixes because this is fairly new and not supported by across all browsers. However, I have noticed that you don't actually need to use **-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent** but can instead just write **color: transparent**.

So my question is: 
What are the benefits of using **-webkit-text-fill-color: transparent** over **color: transparent**?

You can see a comparison of both in action below.

```css
body{background: teal}

p{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 4rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    
    background: url(http://www.jpl.nasa.gov/spaceimages/v2/getMediumImage.php?id=PIA03519) center center;
    
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    
    -webkit-animation: textMask 10s linear infinite;
    animation: textMask 10s linear infinite;
}

.text-fill {
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}

.normal {
    color: transparent;
}

@-webkit-keyframes textMask {
    from {background-position: right bottom}
    to {background-position: left top}
}
@keyframes textMask {
    from {background-position: right bottom}
    to {background-position: left top}
}
```

```html
<p class="text-fill">I am using text-fill-color</p>
<p class="normal">I am just using color</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-webkit-text-fill-color` is just a WebKit-specific variant of `color` that's used in conjunction with `-webkit-text-fill-stroke` (and, as you've seen, `-webkit-background-clip: text`. It is documented in the [Safari CSS Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariCSSRef/Articles/StandardCSSProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001266--webkit-text-fill-color).

There is no difference between `-webkit-text-fill-color` and `color`, except that when both properties are specified, WebKit will use the former. You can use this to your advantage to specify that the text should be transparent only in WebKit-based browsers to allow `-webkit-background-clip: text` to work, while gracefully degrading to some other color in other browsers.

`-webkit-text-fill-color` is not new. It has been part of WebKit since perhaps the very beginning. Whoever told you that it's part of some new and upcoming standard was equally misinformed. Toss the `-moz-` and `-o-` prefixes — they don't exist for this property, because again it's WebKit-specific, and not at all part of CSS3.

Comment: Thanks, I guess this will help me create a fallback for older versions of non-webkit browsers. I have noticed that current non-webkit browsers do support -webkit-background-clip: text;